# How do I create a redirect from one page url to another in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

**Issue:**
I have 2 pages in a Drupal 8 website, let's call them "/page/1" and "/page/2".
I need to force a redirect on "/page/1" so it goes to "/page/2".

How can I do this through the interface?

**What I've tried:**.
I have tried using the standard redirect feature:
Configuration > Search and metadata > Redirect.

But when I go to the URL it doesn't redirect.

Comment: You have redirect Module Installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:
1) using the web server like Apache /nginx. 
If you want go this route , search how do this via vhost of your specific web server&site

```
Redirect permanent /oldlocation http://www.newdomain.com/newlocation
```

2) or install and use the popular redirect module from [Drupal.org/project/redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) 
And configure the urls you want redirect

Comment: I've got the redirect module installed, however it doesn't redirect. It has other redirects working correctly, however it doesn't redirect. I wonder if its because page 1 still exists?

Comment: Do u have aliases? Pathauto enabled? Does the destination exist? Finally, check your logs to see what happened to the request. Don’t forgot to choose an answer here  when done

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Rules Module](https://drupal.org/project/rules). It works for me.